# How can I prevent wall patches from affecting paint sheen?

Tags: paint, repainting, patching-drywall, oil-based-paint, putty

I am trying to paint a wall. I have applied wall putty to cracks in the wall, applied one coat of wall primer (solvent based) then applied one coat of oil based paint.

Where there was no wall putty applied the sheen of the paint is fabulous. On the other hand over the wall putty there are spotty patches of flat paint (with no sheen) even after two coats of paints.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a primer sealer will help, with that said without texture being applied unless the wall was smooth it will always look different, a photo of the area would help provide a better answer.

Comment: If by "flat" he does not mean literally flat, but just matte and uninteresting, it will not be an effect of texture, but rather problem with primer / sealer.